# Does moving from None to Consistent Indexing mode in Cosmos Db re-indexes everything?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The azure cosmos db documentation mentions following in the index transformation section :

> When you move to None indexing mode, the index is dropped immediately. Moving to None is useful when you want to cancel an in-progress transformation and start fresh with a different indexing policy.

I have a partitioned collection with custom indexing policy with indexing mode consistent. Since there is no transformation progress available for a partitioned collection, so before starting any new indexing policy update, I was thinking of using None mode to cancel any in progress transformation and start the new one(consistent mode). But will this cause the entire index to get recreated, even if, just a new path was added?

If answer is yes, what is the best way of checking if no transformation is in progress before starting a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Jatin! I am from the CosmosDB engineering team.

We do have transformation progress now for a partitioned collections - this was released recently. This can be fetched by setting the header 'x-ms-documentdb-populatequotainfo' to True. This header, in addition to providing quota and usage information for a partitioned collection, is also used to piggyback the index transformation progress information for partitioned collections.

However, you do not need to wait for the progress to complete before changing your indexing policy. Even though this would mean that it could take longer for our background re-indexing to finish all previous index updates and catch up to your latest indexing policy, there is an opportunity for the transformations to be online, meaning that queries could continue to work based on the changes between the indexing policy updates. For example, if the only change was adding paths throughout the transformations, queries on paths that are already indexed will continue to work throughout the reindexing process, assuming that the indexing mode was consistent through all the updates.

However, if you want your new index to be effective potentially sooner, then your suggestion of transitioning to None and then to Consistent could work. Please note that this is equivalent to an offline index rebuild, meaning the existing index will be deleted and the new one will be constructed from scratch. Queries will not return consistent results on any path up until the reindexing process completes.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Simply change the indexing policy from `Custom` to `Consistent`. Skip going to `None` and go directly to `Consistent` indexing policy:

> All index transformations are performed online. The items indexed per the old policy are efficiently transformed per the new policy without affecting the write availability or the throughput  provisioned to the container. The consistency of read and write operations that are performed by using the REST API, SDKs, or from stored procedures and triggers is not affected during index transformation.

[Index transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#index-transformations)

> While reindexing is in progress, your query may not return all matching results, if the queries happen to use the index that is being modified, and queries will not return any errors/failures. While reindexing is in progress, queries are eventually consistent regardless of the indexing mode configuration.

If you feel that `None` is safe step before going to `Consistent`, you are free to do so but it is not absolutely necessary.